# Can't Access my 2-D Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, 2d

this is an array that contains the question on index 0 and choices from 1-4 and then on index 5 contains the answer. I want to access these index numbers individually but cant.

```js
questionbank = [
  ["Which city is the capital of Pakistan", "Islamabad", "Karachi", "Lahore", "Quetta", "Islamabad"],
  ["Which city is the capital of U.A.E", "Dubai", "Abu Dhabi", "Sharjah", "Ras Al-Khaimah", "Dubai"],
  ["Which city is the capital of United States of America", "Austin", "Washington DC", "Boston", "Colorado", "Washington DC"],
  ["Which city is the capital of UK", "London", "Manchester", "Leeds", "Sunderland", "London"],
  ["Which city is the capital of Kuwait", "Kuwait City", "Salmiya", "Jahra", "Tokyo", "Kuwait City"],
  ["Which city is the capital of Saudi Arabia", "Riyadh", "Mecca", "Madinah", "Jeddah", "Riyadh"],
  ["Which city is the capital of India", "Mumbai", "Delhi", "Bareilly", "Calcutta", "Mumbai"],
  ["Which city is the capital of Afghanistan", "Kabul", "Kandahar", "Herat", "Jalalabad", "Kabul"],
  ["Which city is the capital of Ireland", "Dublin", "Belfast", "Cork", "Limerick", "Dublin"]
];

function next_question() {
  text = questionbank[0, 0];
  alert(text);
}

next_question();
```

The problem is when i call [0,0] the whole sentence in the array comes up instead of just one element in the array. My array is a collection of questions on position 0 and the collection of choices in the other positions. Can you please tell me how to access only one element of the array at a time!

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the correct syntax to access the second dimension. `[0, 0]` is equivalent to `[0]`. The comma doesn't separate dimensions, it's the comma operator that simply evaluates both operands and returns the second one. A multi-dimensional array is an array of arrays, so you access each dimension with a separate set of brackets: `arrayname[subscript1][subscript2]`

```js
questionbank = [
  ["Which city is the capital of Pakistan", "Islamabad", "Karachi", "Lahore", "Quetta", "Islamabad"],
  ["Which city is the capital of U.A.E", "Dubai", "Abu Dhabi", "Sharjah", "Ras Al-Khaimah", "Dubai"],
  ["Which city is the capital of United States of America", "Austin", "Washington DC", "Boston", "Colorado", "Washington DC"],
  ["Which city is the capital of UK", "London", "Manchester", "Leeds", "Sunderland", "London"],
  ["Which city is the capital of Kuwait", "Kuwait City", "Salmiya", "Jahra", "Tokyo", "Kuwait City"],
  ["Which city is the capital of Saudi Arabia", "Riyadh", "Mecca", "Madinah", "Jeddah", "Riyadh"],
  ["Which city is the capital of India", "Mumbai", "Delhi", "Bareilly", "Calcutta", "Mumbai"],
  ["Which city is the capital of Afghanistan", "Kabul", "Kandahar", "Herat", "Jalalabad", "Kabul"],
  ["Which city is the capital of Ireland", "Dublin", "Belfast", "Cork", "Limerick", "Dublin"]
];

function next_question() {
  text = questionbank[0][0];
  alert(text);
}

next_question();
```

Comment: Thanks! you're awesome :)

Comment: Nice explanation about the comma operator.

Answer (score 1):

To access to two-dimensional array you should use this notation `[0][0]`:

```js
questionbank = [
  ["Which city is the capital of Pakistan", "Islamabad", "Karachi", "Lahore", "Quetta", "Islamabad"],
  ["Which city is the capital of U.A.E", "Dubai", "Abu Dhabi", "Sharjah", "Ras Al-Khaimah", "Dubai"],
  ["Which city is the capital of United States of America", "Austin", "Washington DC", "Boston", "Colorado", "Washington DC"],
  ["Which city is the capital of UK", "London", "Manchester", "Leeds", "Sunderland", "London"],
  ["Which city is the capital of Kuwait", "Kuwait City", "Salmiya", "Jahra", "Tokyo", "Kuwait City"],
  ["Which city is the capital of Saudi Arabia", "Riyadh", "Mecca", "Madinah", "Jeddah", "Riyadh"],
  ["Which city is the capital of India", "Mumbai", "Delhi", "Bareilly", "Calcutta", "Mumbai"],
  ["Which city is the capital of Afghanistan", "Kabul", "Kandahar", "Herat", "Jalalabad", "Kabul"],
  ["Which city is the capital of Ireland", "Dublin", "Belfast", "Cork", "Limerick", "Dublin"]
];

function next_question() {
  text = questionbank[0][0];
  alert(text);
}

next_question();
```

Comment: Thanks! you're awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard notation `[dimension][anotherDimension]...` in your case `[0][0]` instead of `[0,0]`. The last one is not valid in terms of JavaScript or at least does not do what you want. You might have a different background, like C#, where it is a valid multidimensional notation.

Answer (score 0):

This is not `questionbank[0, 0]` but `questionbank[0][0]`.

Comment: Thanks! you're awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a 2d array so you should access like:

```
questionbank[0][0]
```